# Does ubuntu 22.04 able to use dnf reposync to build apt and rpm repository?

Tags: package-management

I want to use a single (and simple enough) tool to build a both apt and rpm repository.
I know `dnf reposync` on Centos is able to build a rpm repository.
Can it able to use on Ubuntu?
I try to run `apt install dnf` on ubuntu, it is successful. But `reposync` is a dnf plugin,
`dnf install 'dnf-command(reposync)` don't work.

How should I install it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have been able to dig up, `reposync` will not work on any *currently supported* version of Ubuntu. There is [a Lunar manpage for this function](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man8/dnf-reposync.8.html), which may mean that Ubuntu 23.04 and newer will support the `reposync` function.

Ubuntu 23.04 is slated for release later this month, but you may be able to *test* whether this newest interim release can do what you need via [the beta](https://releases.ubuntu.com/lunar/).

Comment: yes, i notice this `dnf-plugins-core` package don't exist in `jammy` version. And `yum-utils` which provides `reposync` command only exist in `bionic` and `focal` version. So i asked.

Comment: FYI:    Rather than installing the *beta* (*which is very dated now*), I'd install the latest *daily* ISO, esp. as we get closer to RC (*release candidate*). A large number of fixes have been applied to the ISOs since *beta* was released...   I won't provide link as no desktop/server/etc specific Ubuntu 22.04 product was mentioned